# Different windows with the same code?

Tags: java, swing

This is the "main" class (doesn't contain the main method)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
//import java.lang.Object;
//import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
//import java.awt.event.;

public class Program {

  public JFrame frame;
  public JPanel header;
  public JPanel text;
  public JPanel body;
  public JTextField input;
  public JButton agregar;

  public List listA;
  public List listB;

  public Program(String title) {
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(500,600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    header = new JPanel();
    header.setBackground(new Color(255,204,50));
    header.setBounds(0,0,500,100);

    text = new JPanel();
    text.setBackground(new Color(255,204,100));
    text.setBounds(0,100,500,50);
    text.setLayout(null);

    //Inicializando la "entrada"
    input = new JTextField(20);
    input.setBounds(50,13,300,25);
    text.add(input);

    agregar = new JButton();
    agregar.setBounds(360,12,80,25);
    agregar.setText("Agregar");
    text.add(agregar);
    //Listo

    body = new JPanel();
    body.setBackground(new Color(255,204,150));
    body.setBounds(0,150,500,450);

    //Lo que está dentro del body
    listA = new List(20);
    body.add(listA);

    listB = new List(20);
    body.add(listB);
    //Listo

    //Añadir todos los paneles al frame principal
    frame.add(header);
    frame.add(text);
    frame.add(body);

  }
}
```

And this is the MAIN class (This one contains the main method):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Program("Ordenamiento Recursivo");
  }
}
```

Each time I run the application, the UI components are presented differently, please see attached screen shot.

---

Well, thanks to everyone who responded the post, I finished the program and I'm very happy with the final result, here it is:

[image: Programa para Moquillaza]

In case anyone wants to take a look at the code, here it is: [Link](http://www.copypastecode.com/214612/)

Comment: Here's a pic of what's going on: https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/542011_351231484935185_100001450101764_1038411_1654559456_n.jpg

Comment: What's the problem? Every time you run it you get new window? Of course you will you're starting a new process.

Comment: You might try a put a _bit more effort_ into your question (despite bad english) - it's really hard to figure out what you get, what you expect and thus what _could_ be wrong. Did you try and debug your application?

Comment: I've run the program a lot of times and every time I'm getting a different result, but it's the same code I've been compiling.

Comment: My question is Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems:

- You're call `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame ***before*** adding components and this will lead to unreliable drawing of your program's graphics and is why you are seeing different results. Don't do this, but rather call it *after* you've added all to the top-level Window.
- As the others are saying, read up and learn to use the layout managers.

Answer (score 4):

> Different windows with the same code?

- I think that is very simple and possible by implements [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- I'd suggest don't opening a new [Top-Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), only if is there really important reason then use [JDialog or JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: You mean I have to implement CardLayout or I shouldn't implement CardLayout? I set the Layout to null: 'frame.setLayout(null);'

Comment: @hinafu I think that you have to implement `CardLayout` and don't set `frame.setLayout(null);` JFrame has implemented BorderLayout by Default, then you can call (by suing CardLayout) only `frame.add(myCards);`

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to construct the GUI on the EDT.  Not doing so can cause unpredictable results.

Call `pack()` after the components are added using layouts and **then** call `setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a layout manager for your form so setting the layout manager to null is not the thing to do.

Work in progress here ... https://gist.github.com/2510570

Couple of changes. Not quite finished yet,  but check out the following

1. Have Program extend a JFrame.
2. Have set a layout manager.

Update 
Finally I knocked this up in IntelliJ's form designer.

https://gist.github.com/2512197

Where you want to attach behaviour to the buttons search through the code for the comments that ask you to add code. Although I did this in the InteliJ Ultimate (this one that costs money) I think that no-cost free to download Community Edition UI designer also paints Swings GUIs. Very quick and easy. Netbeans also has a good GUI painter.

The Swing Tutorial on [oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is worth reviewing also.

Comment: *"I will provide an example in the next 30 mins."*  tick.. tick.. tick.. do I get my pizza er.. example for free? ;)

Comment: @Rob one with olivas, cheese and spargla please :-)

Comment: I wanted to do something like this http://k39.kn3.net/6FFF26F0F.jpg , maybe a custom background but I will check that out later

Comment: @hinafu I'm getting a HTTP 403 on k39.kn3.net/6FFF26F0F.jpg can you have a look at that or post it to TwitPic or Flickr?